# the accident happened a mile west of Bowes (Is 'west' an adverb?)

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles, measure-phrases

[The Lexico Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/west) defines a use of 'west' as an adverb:

> To or towards the west.
>
> *he faced **west** and watched the sunset*
>
> *the accident happened a mile **west** of Bowes*

I can easily understand the ***west*** in the first example is an adverb, but I have a hard time understanding or explaining to others how the one in the second is also an adverb.

Is ***west*** in the second example really an adverb? If so, how can you prove that it is?

Comment: I would say that *a mile west of Bowes* is a prepositional phrase that's acting adverbially—and that *west* is just one of the components of the phrase. It's not an adverb on its own. You couldn't really say *the accident happened west*. You have to say *the accident happened **to the** west*, ***in the*** *west*, or (in this case) ***a mile*** *west* or ***west*** *of Bowes*. To call the single word *west* an adverb in the second sentence is misleading.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica No, that's not right.  This is what we call a ***measure phrase***.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your analysis, *west* can be read as an *adverb* or as part of an *adverbial phrase*, defined as a phrase that is functioning as an adverb.

**Traditional Answer: *West* is an adverb modifying the preposition *of* or the prepositional phrase *of Bowes***

For example, the Oxford English Dictionary suggests that in the following example (similar to 2 in your question) *west* is an adverb modifying a preposition ("[west, adv., adj, n.1,](https://oed.com/view/Entry/227885)" A.1.b.(a)):

> 2005   J. Diamond Collapse (2006) vi. 197   Iceland lies in the North Atlantic Ocean about **600 miles west of Norway**.

So *west* would be an adverb that premodifies a preposition. [The Oxford Companion to the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=eRRbDwAAQBAJ&ppis=_e&lpg=PT94&ots=WGcYtwfg6F&dq=adverb%20%22west%22%20modify%20preposition&pg=PT94#v=onepage&q=adverb%20%22west%22%20modify%20preposition&f=false) describes a typical case:

> Apart from modifying adjectives and adverbs, some adverbs may modify prepositions (*well* in *He kicked the ball well past the line*)

This is the simple answer.

**Newer Answer: *West* is an adverbial that can be combined with other adverbials**

It makes sense to treat *west* as an adverb modifying a preposition or a prepositional phrase. That said, doing so neglects a property of *west* - it would also function in the absence of "of Bowes." That suggests that *west* is itself an adverbial of place.

For example, if one took out the *measure phrase* "a mile" or "about 600 miles," the sentences would remain grammatical:

> the accident happened **west** of Bowes.
>
> Iceland lies in the North Atlantic Ocean **west** of Norway.

The adverbial phrases indicate direction, and don't need the measure phrase to function.

Furthermore, removing the prepositional phrase would also result in a grammatical usage, albeit one that requires a contextual understanding of the frame of reference - west *of what*?

> the accident happened a mile west. (OK if we're speaking and I can presume "of here," but not good if I'm reading a newspaper)
>
> Iceland lies in the North Atlantic Ocean 600 miles **west**. (OK if my question was "In relation to Norway, where is Iceland?" but not in more general cases where I might pick Ireland or Greenland as a frame of reference)

So if the prepositional phrase is omitted, there is still a sense that *west* serves as an adverbial signalling direction in relation to a frame of reference, even if that frame of reference is presumed. In this way, *west* would be an adverbial signalling direction, and the fuller phrase *west of Bowes* would be an adverbial phrase.

Comment: Please define 'adverbial'. Is 'adverbial' a part of speech? Is your newer answer agreeing with @Jason Bassford Supports Monica?

Comment: Adjusted to include a definition of "adverbial." It's a method for labeling phrases or clauses that function like adverbs. And yes, my newer answer agrees with @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica, though I also tried to acknowledge that a measure phrase is involved.

Comment: @listeneva No, adverbials are not a part of speech. [Adverbials most commonly take the form of adverbs, adverb phrases, temporal noun phrases, or prepositional phrases. Many types of adverbials (for instance: reason and condition) are often expressed by clauses.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) That's a little squishy because they're trying to distinguish these from syntactic adjuncts here and I'm not sure they should be.